# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm getting this error while reading the data into the dashboard. I am creating a relationship between a post and category table and after assingning the category to the post and calling the category name from the category table to the dashboard im getting this error.
This is in laravel 8

This is the error I am getting
[image: This is the error iam getting]

This is the model post
[image: This is the model post]

This is model category
[image: This is model category]

I caught this error while doing this
[image: I caught this error while doing this]

This is the migration for post table
[image: this is the migration for post table]

This is the migration for category table
[image: this is the migration for category table]

[image: here's my post controlle too]

Comment: Don't post images of code/errors/text. Post the actual code into the question instead. Here you can read why: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What is unclear about _'Table doesn't exist'_?

Comment: I'm sorry I just started my journey today at the stack. next time ill consider that for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your `posts` migration, the `category` relationship in your `Post` model should be [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) not [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

`BelongsToMany` is a many-to-many relationship which requires an intermediate (pivot) table to link the two resources.

Comment: Now i am getting tha error Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance. can you please help if i can find you or contact you somehow

Comment: but this did not fix my problem. I think we need to add another table for joining the post and category with each other.

Comment: @RishikeshKarki Please can you edit your questions and add the route and controller method for this (please copy and paste the code rather than add an image).